# How to tell nextjs to try find page in other dynamic route?

Tags: next.js, dynamic-routing

In my headless cms I have such pages
`/about-us`
`/contact`
`/services/`
`/services/service-1`
`/services/service-3`

Which I handle with `pages/[...slug].js` file.
Now I want to add also some specific services that I want to have custom design and fetch data from another place and handle them with `services/[...slug].js` but face issue that my pages such `/services/service-1`, `/services/service-3` not handles with `services/[...slug].js`file. Is there any way to tell nextjs - if we do not find pages in one place try to render them in another place?

[image]

Comment: According to the [Dynamic Routes docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#caveats), `/pages/services/[...slug].js` should take precedence over `/pages/[...slug].js`as it contains a pre-defined path (`/services`). Have you tried modifying the path to `/pages/services/[slug].js` instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can create specific file like this
pages -> services -> service-3.js

Or you can handle in
pages -> 404.js